# Attribute Inspector Does Not Appear In Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode, ios14

I recently updated my Xcode to Xcode 12 and I got the following issue when I chose any object in my storyboard I couldn't access to the attribute Inspector.

[image]

Does anyone has faced such an issue after updating Xcode?

Comment: I am also having same issue, any solutions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was opening another project that show the attribute inspector when choosing an object and then open the issued project

Answer (score 5):

Restarting Xcode resolved the issue

Comment: I've tried this solution but it dose not working for me, so i made a new project and open my current project, this solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Quit your Xcode and create a new project, then open your project from the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this issue is by opening the file through the project navigator and not opening it with quick access cmd+shift+o. There must be some issue with quick open that doesn't go through necessary mechnisms that the project navigator does.

is this photo the problem you were facing? Xcode 14.3[image]